# Laravel 5.3 - ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 414

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, autoloader

I am using Laravel 5.3. I have just installed intervention/image package in my project. Everything is working fine but I am facing an error on a page. I have searched a lot to resolve it but i am unable to solve it. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. The Larave 5.3 error i'm facing is:

```
ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 414:
include(/opt/lampp/htdocs/stellarWinds/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/FunnelStepsController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It was working good before i installed intervention/image

Comment: you have define  FunnelStepsController ..?

Comment: Yes i've defined this in app/Http/Controllers directory.

Comment: could you check your namespace ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have resolved it by using the following command -

composer dumpautoload

Thank You "D Coder" and "jaysingkar" for your help.

Comment: WOrked like a charm too. Laravel 5.6

Comment: This happens because probably a migration has been created manually instead of using the php artisan command to create it? Learned by mistake as well